# I own a domain and attempt to setup Google App account and find another company is using my domain

Tags: google-workspace

I purchased a domain a few months back and I want to setup a Google Apps account.  When setting up the account Google tells my the domain is already registered to a Google Apps account.

I attempt to login to the account and am told it is owned by a company other than my own.  When I google search for the company I find that it is no longer in business.

How to I go about getting Google Apps setup for my domain?  Google does not provide any methods to directly contact them via any means and I can find no other way to resolve my issue.

Comment: You'll need to call/contact customer service

Answer (score 3):

If you own the domain and have access to its file system, you can reset the Google apps password for that domain [using Domain verification](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33561).

If that doesn't help, here are [some more helps](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1071497) to follow.